# iOS10 failed to play custom sounds when recovering to install app

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications, ios10, xcode8

I am currently running iOS 10 with Xcode 8.0 and the custom sound of Push Notifications does not play when I receive a push notification with the correct payload.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It works when I remove that app first and reinstall that app. But it doesn't work when I recover that app. What wrong with the issue in iOS10?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I found that after rebooting the device, the custom notification works again. Is this the same for you?

Comment: No, no matter rebooting or not , it always does not work. It works only when removing app first then installing a new one.